# How to combine two dataframes into one and aggregate common records in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

df1:

```
Date                Code        Name    Rating        x             y          z
2022-07-27 00:00:00 OMER       OMERS    I-2       2027983745    2029539000  1555255.31
2022-07-27 00:00:00 SC        SOCIETY   I-7       389659466.4   391147968.2 1488501.805
2022-07-27 00:00:00 CD      CORPORATION I-3       2692692761    2694172512  1479750.8
2022-07-27 00:00:00 PRIN        AGENT   I-3       72990460.96   74455570    1465109.042
2022-07-27 00:00:00 BF          FUND    S-3       277607047.4   279044540.2 1437492.761
```

df2:

```
Date                     Code             Name      Rating            x       y     z
2022-07-27 00:00:00      BankA             nan       nan            1052    1052    0
2022-07-27 00:00:00       CD           CORPORATION   I-3            1943    2000    57
2022-07-27 00:00:00      CorporationA      nan       nan            1943    3052    1109
```

Expected Output:

```
Date                Code            Name    Rating        x             y          z
2022-07-27 00:00:00 OMER            OMERS   I-2       2027983745    2029539000  1555255.31
2022-07-27 00:00:00 SC             SOCIETY  I-7       389659466.4   391147968.2 1488501.805
2022-07-27 00:00:00 CD          CORPORATION I-3       2692694704    2694174512  1479807.8
2022-07-27 00:00:00 PRIN           AGENT    I-3       72990460.96   74455570    1465109.042
2022-07-27 00:00:00 BF              FUND    S-3       277607047.4   279044540.2 1437492.761
2022-07-27 00:00:00 BankA           nan     nan         1052           1052         0
2022-07-27 00:00:00 CorporationA    nan     nan         1943           3052        1109
```

I want to combined df1 and df2 into one dataframe. In DF2 if the "code", "Name","Rating" are already present in df1, need to sum the values of x,y and z into one row and if not available just append the value in the bottom of the dataframe. Appreciate your help in this! Thank you

[image]

Comment: `pd.concat([df1,df2], on="Date")`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to merge two data frames based on particular column in pandas python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37697195/how-to-merge-two-data-frames-based-on-particular-column-in-pandas-python)

Comment: Nope, I want to combined df1 and df2 into one dataframe. In DF2 if the "code", "Name","Rating" are already present in df1, need to sum the values of x,y and z into one row and if not available, just append the values in the bottom of the dataframe for example(BankA and Corporation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `pd.concat` then `groupby.agg`

```py
cols1 = ['x', 'y', 'z']
cols2 = ['Code', 'Name', 'Rating']
d = {col: 'sum' if col in cols1 else 'first' for col in df1.columns}

df2[cols2] = df2[cols2].fillna('NaN')
out = (pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index=True)
       .groupby(cols2)
       .agg(d).reset_index(drop=True))
```

```
print(out)

                  Date          Code         Name Rating              x              y           z
0  2022-07-27 00:00:00            BF         FUND    S-3  277607047.400  279044540.200 1437492.761
1  2022-07-27 00:00:00         BankA          NaN    NaN       1052.000       1052.000       0.000
2  2022-07-27 00:00:00            CD  CORPORATION    I-3 2692694704.000 2694174512.000 1479807.800
3  2022-07-27 00:00:00  CorporationA          NaN    NaN       1943.000       3052.000    1109.000
4  2022-07-27 00:00:00          OMER        OMERS    I-2 2027983745.000 2029539000.000 1555255.310
5  2022-07-27 00:00:00          PRIN        AGENT    I-3   72990460.960   74455570.000 1465109.042
6  2022-07-27 00:00:00            SC      SOCIETY    I-7  389659466.400  391147968.200 1488501.805
```